# Use case of Authenticator#requestPasswordAuthentication​

Tags: java, java-11

I can not figure out the actual use case of `Authenticator#requestPasswordAuthentication​` method from `java.net`. I understand that it has something to do with the `HttpClient` to request authentication but can't figure out how it would work. Does it has anything to do with http basic authentication?

My second question is that there are `String host, InetAddress addr` as method parameter of `requestPasswordAuthentication​`. Why do we need to specify a `InetAddress` when we already specified the `host`? Afaik, `InetAddress` is used to encapsulate ip address. So if we already specified the ip address, why does it need a `host`?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question 1:If a password is required,there are relationships.
Answer to question 2:Because `InetAddress` object is your local host.If you have multiple IP addresses,you can decide to bind one of your addresses.Like `Socket.bind(SocketAddress)`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this test case to understand it:

```
@Test
void requestPasswordAuthentication() {
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    var upass = Authenticator.requestPasswordAuthentication(
            inetAddress, -1, "", "", "");
    assertEquals("uname", upass.getUserName());
    assertEquals("password", String.valueOf(upass.getPassword()));
}
```